# Android: clipToPadding in LinearLayout with child ListView ignored?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, fragment, android-linearlayout

I have a rather strange issue that I'm hoping someone can shed light on. I'm not sure if it's an Android bug or not.

I have the following layout displayed in a fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.testapp.test.TestFragment"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/data_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Even though I have set clipToPadding to be false, my ListView is still clipping to the padding of my LinearLayout!

A work-around is to remove the top and bottom padding from the LinearLayout and add it to the ListView with clipToPadding set to false on the ListView, but I would rather not do that, as in a special case, I may want to hide the ListView to show, for example, the TextView below it (and off-screen) while keeping the padding, and would like to avoid adding extra complexity into the layout.

**Update:**
With some testing, I found something interesting. Setting clipToPadding on the parent LinearLayout has no effect because the ListView itself doesn't scroll inside the parent LinearLayout, but rather, the children within the ListView scroll within the ListView! It seems obvious now after some investigation with the debugging tools. The children are limited to the space inside the ListView itself, and because the ListView is set inside the padding of the LinearLayout, and doesn't move, the children scroll within that space.

Here is an ASCII diagram I drew:

```
--------- <LinearLayout>
|       | 
|       | [ Padding ]
|       | 
| ----- | <ListView>
| | c | |
| | o | |
| | n | | Content scrolls
| | t | | within ListView
| | e | | ListView doesn't move
| | n | |
| | t | |
| ----- | </ListView>
|       | 
|       | [ Padding ]
|       | 
--------- </LinearLayout>
```

Simon Marquis's solution was the same as my work-around. Not the solution I wanted to go with, as now I need to add extra padding to every child of my LinearLayout, but a solution, so it is the accepted answer. Thanks, Simon for your input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ListView should have the clipToPadding property instead of the LinearLayout (and it should also contain the padding rather than the LinearLayout with the scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay property so that the scrollbar can be placed in the margins of the app). See the Source for more information:

```
<ListView
    …
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
```

[Source](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/LpAA7q4jw9M)

Comment: No, sorry. I have already tried to set the clipToPadding property of both the listView and the LinearLayout, as mentioned.

Comment: Well, actually, it perfectly works when used with ListView. Official sample code and I already tried it multiple times.

Comment: As I understand, you want me to remove padding from the LinearLayout, and put it, instead into the ListView, as in my workaround?
Yes, that does work... but is a work-around. It means I would need to add padding to the ProgressBar too in order to get the look I need, and that's adding extra complexity into the layout that wouldn't need to be there is the clipToPadding property was working in the LinearLayout

Comment: Sure, but instead, you could wrap your ProgressBar and your TextView inside a container that have padding.

Comment: That is true... but it is still a work-around. It works around the clipToPadding not working in the parent LinearLayout as it should. I am looking for a way to resolve the issue, find a solution without adding extra complexity in an work-around, or get confirmation that there is indeed a bug. Perhaps it's not working because of something small I overlooked. Thanks for your recommendations anyway.

Comment: I think this attribute only works for the direct childs. So, if you use it on a listview parent, it won't have any effect on the listview. If you set it on the ListView, it will have effect on all of its childrens (list elements)

Comment: But since ListView is a direct child of LinearLayout in my layout, setting the attribute on the LinearLayout should have an effect on the ListView, which it does not, right?

Comment: It will have effect on the listview itself, but not on its children. So it will clip the listview children

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now. It is rather confusing though. As I imagine it, the property should should propagate down the view through a child view's children too. I will try to find a solution to keep my padding and have the children not clip too, otherwise, I will select your solution as the answer, thanks.

Comment: Actually, with some testing, I found something interesting. Your explanation as to why this doesn't work seems may be incorrect. Setting clipToPadding on the parent LinearLayout has no effect because the ListView itself doesn't scroll! The children are limited to the space inside the ListView itself. The clipToPadding property does affect children. My ListView's children contain a complex layout of many nested views.